# Compiling Ceph on CentOS 5: `doc_DATA' is used but `docdir' is undefined?

Tags: centos5, distributed-filesystem, ceph

Has anyone sucessfully compiled [`Ceph`](http://ceph.com/) on the CentOS 5?

```
[user@host ceph-0.56.4]# make
...

checking boost/spirit.hpp usability... 
src/Makefile.am:1115: `doc_DATA' is used but `docdir' is undefined
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
yes
```

Line 1115 in the `src/Makefile.am`:

```
# work around old versions of automake that don't define $docdir
# NOTE: this won't work on suse, where docdir is /usr/share/doc/packages/$package.
docdir ?= ${datadir}/doc/ceph

doc_DATA = $(srcdir)/sample.ceph.conf sample.fetch_config
```

I have tried to change the `docdir` to the absolute path:

```
docdir = /usr/share/doc/ceph
```

but it doesn't help.

```
# rpm -qa | grep automake
automake16-1.6.3-8.el5.1
automake15-1.5-16.el5.2
automake-1.9.6-2.3.el5
automake17-1.7.9-7.el5.2
automake14-1.4p6-13.el5.1
```

What surprised me is in the `ceph.spec`, I see:

```
%{configure}    CPPFLAGS="$java_inc" \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --sbindir=/sbin \
        --localstatedir=/var \
        --sysconfdir=/etc \
        --docdir=%{_docdir}/ceph \
        --without-hadoop \
        --with-nss \
        --without-cryptopp \
        --with-rest-bench \
        --with-debug \
        --enable-cephfs-java \
        $MY_CONF_OPT \
        %{?_with_ocf} \
        %{?with_tcmalloc:--with-tcmalloc} %{!?with_tcmalloc:--without-tcmalloc} \
        CFLAGS="$RPM_OPT_FLAGS" CXXFLAGS="$RPM_OPT_FLAGS"
```

but there is no `--docdir` configure option when searching through the `./configure --help`.

I know CentOS 5 is quite old but is there any workaround in this situation?

---

**UPDATE Thu Apr  4 23:05:53 ICT 2013**

[Ceph](http://ceph.com/download/) 0.46 was compiled successfully, but now I get:

```
# ceph-fuse --no-fuse-big-writes -m 192.168.2.15:6789 /mnt/ceph/
ceph-fuse[7528]: starting ceph client
ceph-fuse[7528]: starting fuse
fuse: unknown option `atomic_o_trunc'
2013-04-04 13:51:21.128506 2b82d6e9e8f0 -1 fuse_lowlevel_new failed
ceph-fuse[7528]: fuse finished with error 33
ceph-fuse[7526]: mount failed: (33) Numerical argument out of domain
```

http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/4286

Answer (score 0):

While none of the kernel clients will work, ceph *used* to run on CentOS 5. There is, of course, a chance that some nasty build issues have been introduced though.  I know we test packages for  RHEL/CentOS 6 ( http://ceph.com/rpm/el6/ ), but I don't think anyone has looked at 5 in a while.

When it was being built on 5 I know there were a bunch of dependencies if you get that far:

autotools-dev
autoconf
automake
cdbs
g++
gcc
git
libatomic-ops-dev
libboost-dev
libcrypto++-dev
libcrypto++
libedit-dev
libexpat1-dev
libfcgi-dev
libfuse-dev
libgoogle-perftools-dev
libgtkmm-2.4-dev
libtool
pkg-config

Sorry I can't answer your question specifically, but it has been quite a while since anyone around here looked at Ceph on Cent5. If you stop by irc://irc.oftc.net/ceph someone might be able to give you a better historical perspective than I can.

Good luck.

---

[EDIT]: Just talked to someone who went through and made it work.  He had this to say: "It took compiling GCC, all of the GNU libs, autoconf, automake, probably about 10-20 other libraries and of course ceph itself." So, it's possible...just not recommended. Hope that helps.